# Beautify for loop using stream and lambda

Tags: java, java-stream

Currently I got this code:

```
@GetMapping("/all/")
    public Iterable<Article> getAllArticle(){
        ArrayList<ArticleEntity> articleEntities = Lists.newArrayList(articleProviderComponent.getAllArticle());
        ArrayList<Article> articles = Lists.newArrayList();
        for(ArticleEntity articleEntity : articleEntities){
            articles.add(ArticleMapper.articleEntity2Article(articleEntity));
        }
        return articles;
    }
```

The repository returns an `Iterable`, which I want to convert to a `ArrayList`. Beside that I want to convert each `Entity` to a `POJO`.

I tried using something like 
`list.foreach(ArticleMapper::ArticleMapper.articleEntity2Article)` which works fine, but does not return a new list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple `map` will do the job:

```
List<Article> articles = articleEntities.stream()
                                        .map(ArticleMapper::articleEntity2Article)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`map` converts each element to something else using the method given.

Answer (score 4):

Stream the `List`, `map` it to your target type and `collect` to a `List`:

```
List<Article> articles = articleEntities.stream().map(ArticleMapper::articleEntity2Article).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the other answers are showing the right direction. But if you want to keep the same semantics  of your code something additional has to be taken into account.

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) `Collecotrs.toList`

> Returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new
>   `List`. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability,
>   serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more
>   control over the returned `List` is required, use
>   `toCollection(Supplier)`.

The returned `articles` are of type `ArrayList<ArticleEntity>`. Thus this list is e.g. mutable.

The return type of the method `getAllArticle()` is `Iterable<Article>`. Thus we can call

```
Iterator<Article> iterator = getAllArticle().iterator();
```

But if you need to call `iterator.remove()` "there are no guarantees on the [...] mutability" of the underlying collection. Hence this could result in an ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()))

> UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not
>   supported by this iterator

To keep the behaviour of the original code use `Collectors.toCollection`:

```
List<Article> articles = articleEntities.stream()
        .map(ArticleMapper::articleEntity2Article)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Lists::newArrayList));
```

This will return `articles` built by `Lists.newArrayList()`.

Answer (score 0):

As `Iterable` is made to be as **general** as possible, it does not provide a capability to **stream** it's content, but with the help of `StreamSupport` you can generate a `stream` from the `Iterable` instance and reduce the amount of operations to **one**:

```
final List<Article> articlesList = 
 StreamSupport.stream(articleProviderComponent.getAllArticle().spliterator(), false)            
 .map(ArticleMapper::articleEntity2Article)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```